# Can the "any" type be disabled in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

According to the documentation for the [`any` type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/), "Using any is completely unsafe, and should be avoided whenever possible". That sounds reasonable, so I'd like to ensure I don't introduce any `any` types by accident.

But in the documentation for [external libraries](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) it says:

> If a third-party library that has no type information is used by your project, Flow will treat it like any other untyped dependency and mark all of its exports as any. Interestingly, this is the only place that Flow will implicitly inject any into your program.

My question is, can I turn off that implicit injection of the `any` type? I would like to statically ensure sure that I have correctly provided libdefs for all dependencies.

Comment: I remember that Flow will warn you whenever you use `any`. Also, use ESLint with Flowtype plugin will warn you even more. And currently, the libdefs for Flow is not as much as TS, so you will have to manually write them if you want to cover all.

Comment: I don't think either of those tools will warn about the *implicit* injection of the `any` type that my question is asking.

Comment: No, they doensn't. But when you use those library, you will have the error ["required module not found"](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2092), and Flow will treat what you imported from it as `any`.